# bash script increment number at end with zero prefix

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

given a file with contents like this:

```
foo: 8.3.1
bar: 803001
```

I need a bash script to read this file *only* increment the last digit and consider the second line's last three digits as space for the the z in x.y.x to grow to three digits (and overwrite the original file with the new data:

Input 1:

```
foo: 8.3.1
bar: 803001
```

Output 1:

```
 foo: 8.3.2
 bar: 803002
```

Input 2:

```
foo: 8.3.9
bar: 803009
```

Output 2:

```
 foo: 8.3.10
 bar: 803010
```

Input 3:

```
foo: 8.3.199
bar: 803199
```

Output 3:

```
 foo: 8.3.200
 bar: 803200
```

I could do this in 2 seconds in java but I need to do it in a shell script or i'll face endless taunting from the build team.

Short of some rough string splitting any slick `sep` command would be a big help!

Comment: fixed typo thanks - what i need is the first line's third digit to increment and the second line to contain the first line's numbers without the decimal points and taking into account the third digit can be 000 through 999 :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
 awk -v d='.' '{n=split($2,v,d); 
                if (n>1) $2=v[1] d v[2] d v[3]+1; 
                else $2++}1' file
```

depending what else is in the file, you may need to qualify the replacement with a condition before the statement.

Answer (score 4):

```
while read key val _; do
  val_left="${val%.*}" val_right="${val##*.}"
  printf '%s ' "$key"
  [[ $val = *.* ]] && printf '%s.' "$val_left"
  printf '%d\n' $(( 1+val_right ))
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Bikeshedding and slightly golfing. Increment the number formed by the digits at the end of line:

```
perl -i -pe '/^(foo|bar):/ && s/\d+$/$&+1/e;' input
```